# Tiny MCE How to add meta tags and links in head by default

Tags: tinymce

I am working on Tiny MCE but I stuck because I have to add meta tags and links manually.
I want this by default in Tiny MCE

> [head]   [link href="some cdn"]   [meta name="viewport"
>   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"]   [title]
>   any thing[/title]
>   [/head]

please help

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `fullpage` plugin TinyMCE will allow you to manage the content as an entire HTML page - normally you are just working with the content within the `<body>` tag.

Once you are using the `fullpage` plugin you can load whatever content you need into the editor including the data you want within the `<head>`.